# Finding Control in ItemTemplate of Listview in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Listview with some custom ItemTemplate as ContentView in Xamarin Forms.
I need to change data binding on click on some button in that list.

But I am not able to find out the controls in code-behind.

Is there any way for that?

```
<ListView  HasUnevenRows="true"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                    x:Name="lstInbox">
                         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                 <ViewCell>
                                     <uikit:GraphTemplate/>
                                </ViewCell>
                             </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  </ListView>
```

Comment: I don't really see what you want to change, you want to change the list items?, you want to change some data of some item? , can you put some code?

Comment: @Mulflar Thank for the reply. I want to change the data of the items inside template. I Have a graph inside list and some criteria of graph selection. On click of any of those link I want to bind the graph. Check the update. The GraphTemplate contains another list and a graph Control.

Comment: On click of any item from the other list. I need to change the graph. Because I am not able to find the listview control, so I have written code on contentView Codebehind but due to this the same content is getting binded everywhere.

Comment: Sorry but I never worked with uikit Graphs yet... But I need you need to find what properties of the GraphTemplates are bindables, and then make a function on your ViewModelClass who changes that properties on the click.